# Input value is read only in React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state, javascript-objects

I have multiple color inputs that are being displayed with unique colors. They are getting their value from a helper which is a nested Object. When I attempt to update the value, nothing occurs. My end goal is to change the color inputs and have said color applied to a css variable in order to chnage the specific syntax highlight color.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fbijx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to the project.

Comment: Please do not just link to your code. Try embedding the parts necessary to solve your problem directly into the question. More information on how to improve the question can be found in the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 0):

**ColorPicker.js** - Change in two place *ColorSwatch* and *HexInput* component.

from

```
onChange={props.onColorChange}
```

to

```
onChange={props.onChange}
```

complete ColorPicker.js

```
return (
    <ColorPickerContainer>
      <p>{props.label}</p>
      <ColorSwatch type="color" value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
      <HexInput
        type="text"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
    </ColorPickerContainer>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

just make following changes:

in ColorPickerSection.jsx

```
function ColorPickerSection() {
  const [colorVal, setColorVal] = useState(colors);

  const onColorChange = (e, colorValKey) => {
    setColorVal({
      ...colors,
      [colorValKey]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  console.log(colorVal);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(colorSelect).map(groupName => {
        return (
          <div>
            <GroupName>{groupName}</GroupName>
            {Object.keys(colorSelect[groupName]).map(color => {
              return (
                <ColorPicker
                  key={color}
                  label={color}
                  value={colorVal[color]}
                  onColorChange={e => onColorChange(e, color)}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

in ColorPicker.jsx

```
function ColorPicker(props) {
  return (
    <ColorPickerContainer>
      <p>{props.label}</p>
      <ColorSwatch
        type="color"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onColorChange}
      />
      <HexInput
        type="text"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onColorChange}
      />
    </ColorPickerContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here
  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-heykm

Change HexInput Onchange Methode like this:

```
          onChange={ e => props.onChange(e, props.label)}
```

Change ColorPicker props like this

```
         <ColorPicker
              key={color}
              label={color}
              value={colorVal[color]}
              onChange={onColorChange}
            />
```